# how to change mention link back to GitLab CE in jira?

Tags: jira, gitlab-ci

I have Jira server integrated by Gitlab. Recently I had to change my Gitlab server ip. I have a problem now, Once I Mention a commit to an issue in Jira when I click on Link Back in Jira, the hyperlink redirect me to my old Gitlab IP.
So, How to change Gitlab Link back in Jira?

https://i.ibb.co/SJVPNzv/jira-int.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. After change gitlab IP address, you must change external_url in Gitlab config file in : /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

after reload configuration my problem solved.

for reload:

gitlab-ctl reconfigure

gitlab-ctl restart

Enjoy